# How can I improve the performance of this Zend_Search_Lucene query?

Tags: zend-framework, search, lucene, zend-search-lucene

How can I improve the query as seen below?

My index is fully optimized and all fields are unstored except for item_id which is a keyword field.

The problem is in the "if ($auth) {" section.  If this section is removed search times are always under 1 sec but when this section is added in search times are 5 sec or more.  Obviously it's a more complex query but I can't live without it.  I need the logic in that section to get only search results that the user is authorized to view. I know the slowdown is in the search effort itself because if I remove the line "if ($authQuery) { $query->addSubquery($authQuery, true); }" the search is quite fast.

I'm trying to basically effect the following logic in the "if ($auth) {" section:

lucene fields gi_aro, gc_aro, i_access and c_access all consist of nothing more than a single integer each

```
if ((array_in({gi_aro}, $gmid) OR {i_access} <= $gid)
    AND (array_in({gc_aro}, $gmid) {OR c_access} <= $gid)) {
  include in search results
}
```

{} = lucene fields

```
// keywords query
$keywords = explode(' ', $keyword);

$keywordQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Multiterm();
foreach ($keywords as $term) {
  $keywordQuery->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($term, 'content'));
  $keywordQuery->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($term, 'search_display_name'));
}

// topcat query
if (!empty($topcat)) {
  $term = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($topcat, 'topcats');
  $topcatQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Term($term);
}

// cat query
if (!empty($cat)) {
  $term = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($cat, 'cats');
  $catQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Term($term);
}

// only authorized items query
if ($auth) {
  $user = JFactory::getUser();
  $gid = (int)$user->get('aid');
  $gmid = explode(',', $user->gmid);

  // flexicontent cat auth
  $gcQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();
  foreach ($gmid as $g) {
    $gcQuery->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($g, 'gc_aro'));
  }

  // stock joomla cat auth
  $lowCAccessTerm = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term(0, 'c_access');
  $highCAccessTerm = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($gid, 'c_access');
  $cAccessQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Range($lowCAccessTerm, $highCAccessTerm, true);

  // ORed flexicontent cat auth & stock joomla cat auth
  $catAuthQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean();
  $catAuthQuery->addSubquery($gcQuery);
  $catAuthQuery->addSubquery($cAccessQuery);

  // flexicontent itm auth
  $giQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();
  foreach ($gmid as $g) {
    $giQuery->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($g, 'gi_aro'));
  }

  // stock joomla itm auth
  $lowIAccessTerm = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term(0, 'i_access');
  $highIAccessTerm = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($gid, 'i_access');
  $iAccessQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Range($lowIAccessTerm, $highIAccessTerm, true);

  // ORed flexicontent itm auth & stock joomla itm auth
  $itmAuthQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean();
  $itmAuthQuery->addSubquery($giQuery);
  $itmAuthQuery->addSubquery($iAccessQuery);

  // ANDed itmAuthQuery & catAuthQuery
  $authQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean();
  $authQuery->addSubquery($catAuthQuery, true);
  $authQuery->addSubquery($itmAuthQuery, true);
}

// composite query
$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean();
$query->addSubquery($keywordQuery, true);
// if cat query is set we don't need topcat to restrict result set
if ($catQuery) {
  $query->addSubquery($catQuery, true);
} elseif ($topcatQuery) {
  $query->addSubquery($topcatQuery, true);
}
if ($authQuery) { $query->addSubquery($authQuery, true); }

// search
$execTime = new JProfiler();
$this->hits = $index->find($query);
echo $execTime->mark('executed');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about checking only the results not inside the index? Save some sort of key into the index (db primary key, guid, practically anything). Then fetch the results and remove those which the user is not allowed to see.

```
$allowedArray = $acl->getAllowedIds();
// check happens when echoing the content to prevent double cycling (filtering and echoing in view)
foreach ($result as $item) {
    if (in_array($item->keyVaue, $allowedArray)) {
        //echo
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Note it depends on the result of most queries. If there are say <50 result in regular query, then doing it in PHP is OK. But if common query returns like 10,000 results, it might not be a good idea ;)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for responding but the query routinely returns more than 1000 results and looping through them all just takes too much time.  I was doing that before, but then I realized that the loop was far too costly so I set out to reduce the result set and only "touch" the results I'm going to display but then the search got too slow.  I don't remember how but I got it to run acceptably for the time being.  If it gets too slow I guess I'll have to switch to Solr.

Comment: Other option would be fallback to SQL :)